Are Sado and Orihime fullbringers?
I've been wondering whether or not Sado and Orihime are fullbringers as its never confirmed and they aren't seen using a bringer light, though Orihime uses her earing to manifest her powers we havent seen chad use his pendant.  If they aren't fullbringers, what are they?

Hmmm.... According to the internet, it says that Chad and Orihime are classified as fullbringers.
Chad

This also awakens what Chad later learns to be his latent powers as a
Fullbringer, a human who manipulates the soul of an object to its full
potential as the result of absorbing residual spirit pressure from a
Hollow while unborn.

Orihime

Orihime is classified as a Fullbringer. This is hinted at in the manga
and is confirmed in the secondary novel Can't Fear Your Own World
(CFYOW). However she is also has her powers thanks to the Hogyoku.

